# Pythonic way to extract common logic from a method within a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I recently found out that Guido said that static methods are essentially "an accident".

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2012-May/014969.html

Now my question is how can I extract common logic used by different functions within a class.

I have been doing something like the following:

```
class ChildClass(ParentClass):

    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        super().__init__(self.foo, self.bar)

    @classmethod
    def from_var3(cls, baz):
        foo, bar = baz.split(',')
        return cls(foo, bar)

    @staticmethod
    def _common_method(qux):
        quux = qux  # do_something
        return quux

    def method1(self):
        qux = [f"{x}-something" for x in self.foo]
        quux = ChildClass._common_method(qux)

        return quux

    def method2(self):
        qux = [f"{x}-somethingelse" for x in self.foo]
        corge = ChildClass._common_method(qux)
        # do something with corge
        return corge

    def method3(self):
        qux = [f"{x}-somethingcompletelyelse" for x in self.foo]
        qux.sort(key=ChildClass._common_method)
```

but after thinking about the fact that this static method wouldn't and shouldn't be used from the class level, I am trying to think of a better way.

I thought of the following way as well, but I am not sure a top-level method and a top-level class in the same module is pythonic(It looks dirty from my persepctive). Also I don't want to put this one method in a common module and call from there.

```
def _common_method(qux):
    quux = qux  # do_something
    return quux

class ChildClass(ParentClass):

    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        super().__init__(self.foo, self.bar)

    @classmethod
    def from_var3(cls, baz):
        foo, bar = baz.split(',')
        return cls(foo, bar)


    def method1(self):
        qux = [f"{x}-something" for x in self.foo]
        quux = _common_method(qux)

        return quux

    def method2(self):
        qux = [f"{x}-somethingelse" for x in self.foo]
        corge = _common_method(qux)
        # do something with corge
        return corge

    def method3(self):
        qux = [f"{x}-somethingcompletelyelse" for x in self.foo]
        qux.sort(key=_common_method)
```

Is there a better way to accomplish the extraction of a common logic within a class without making it a static method?

Comment: What you have is fine. `_common_method` (despite its name) is just an ordinary function that operates on certain kinds of lists, and each of your methods can use the to operate on different examples of that kind.

Comment: There are some options which lead to the same effect: 1) static method. 2) normal method with unused parameter `self` 3) top-level function. Static method is imho preferable.

Comment: @chepner which approach you mean? a top-level function or the static method approach

Comment: @sanyash I was also using static method but if guido says it was an accident then tI think there must be a better way to achieve what I want to do.

Comment: Don't take these words about "accident" so seriously. Static method are sometimes useful. Making a static method instead of top-level function is a perfect case for static methods.

Comment: It was an "accident", but that doesn't necessarily mean it was a "mistake". True, if he'd gotten class methods right the first time, he may not have added explicit static methods to the language (or they would have been added later, if enough people asked for ways to group ordinary functions into a single namespace), but I'd say it's a matter of personal preference whether to use a top-level function or a static method. (I lean towards the top-level function unless there's no conceivable use for the function out side of its used by the other methods.)